# Get value in TCPDF

Tags: conditional-tags

I'm work on generation PDF from TCPDF in my current wp project, i have value:

```
$v4 = unserialize(get_post_meta(get_post_meta($dog_id, 'nd_prod', true), 'np_str_ot_summ', true))[0];
```

in my TCPD i use this as output data:

```
<td style="text-align:center; font-size:9px; line-height=8px">
                '.str_replace("." , "," , $v4).'
</td>
```

and in principle all good, but i need add condition: if not data, add text: No records, how i can do this?

Upd.

try add:

```
if(isset($v41)){
         $v41 = str_replace("." , "," , $v4);
         }else{
         $v41 = 'No records';    
        }
```

outputted only No records - but records - present

Comment: Show an example of `$v4` that is 'data'.  And use the WP function `maybe_unserialize` instead of the php function. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_unserialize/

Comment: '.str_replace("." , "," , $v4).' because data what  i have outputted via dots, so str_replace i added and via comma

and unserialize working, you can see my code line for $v4

Comment: You switched from `$v4` to `$v41`.  Try your isset check with `$v4`.  And use `var_dump( $v4 );` before the isset check so you can see what the value is.